# How to check out bound network stats in AWS EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

There is only one network interface in EC2 instance, and in the CloudWatch metric, I can only see `"Max Network In"` and `"Max Network Out"`.

As you know external traffic is billed (actually only outbound), is it possible to check my out bound traffic so I can easily compute the cost?

Comment: Under metrics, CloudWatch should let you choose 'EC2', which should give a list of instances and their associated metrics. One of these will be 'NetworkOut'. After selecting that, you should be able to choose a statistic - select 'Sum' and '1 day', and change the time period (to the max of 2 weeks). This will show you (on a graph) the total daily outbound traffic from your instance for each of the preceding 14 days. (Note this is insufficient to calculate your bandwidth costs - it is too short a time period, and does not break down transfer by destination).

Comment: Just to amend the above - if you pull either daily or weekly CloudWatch stats, then you would have enough information for a decent estimate of bandwidth (or if you use the premium Cloudwatch, which keeps data for a longer time). An indirect solution might be to consider [AWS detailed billing](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/getbill.html#allocation) which will give you hourly usage and cost statistics. If you don't mind scripting something, you can calculate deltas on your ifconfig (eth0) 'TX bytes'.

Answer (score 1):

You can install iftop in your ubuntu server (sudo apt-get install iftop)
then run the command in terminal "iftop"

it will display you all in/out traffic realtime in terminal.